# How to create a table where the value of a field is based on previous row in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
Date    |  Column_A  | Column_B
Day 1   |    5       |    7
Day 2   |    -3      |   7 + (-3) = 4
Day 3   |    8       |   4 + 8 = 12
Day 4   |    -21     |   12 + (-21) -> 0 (see formula on row n)
Day n-1 |    ...     |    Column_B(n-1)
Day n   |Column_A(n) |    IF(Column_B(n-1) + Column_A(n) >= 0, Column_B(n-1) +
                                                                Column_A(n), 0)
```

How to populate Column_B in Mysql ?

Comment: are the dates in sequence or do they not necessarily have to be?

Comment: i meant is Day N *ALWAYS* Day N-1 + one day?  can there be any size gaps between two adjacent rows or is it always incremented by 1 day?

Comment: No there are no gaps. It's always incremented by 1

Comment: does this need to be an INSERT or an UPDATE?

Comment: It has to be an UPDATE or a SELECT, ideally a select. If it's UPDATE then there can't be any nested SELECT inside the UPDATE. Ex: UPDATE my_table SET Column_B = Column_A + (SELECT....) isn't supported

Comment: but the values are not consistent with your formula.  it should be if(col_b(n-1) + col_a(n) > 0, col_b(n-1) + col_a(n), 0)

Comment: Re-formulated the question. It can't be an UPDATE. It has to be a SELECT.

Answer (score 1):

I create a Select that can bring that, I don't find a way to put it into a update.

```
set @col_c:=7;
select *,if(dt!=1,
@col_c:=@col_c+if(col_a<0,col_a,col_a),0) as with_neg_values,
if(@col_c<0,0,@col_c) as col_tot 
from t1
```

SQLFIDDLE: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/105aa/3

Answer (score 0):

Update Query:

```
 update table1 firstInstance, tabe1 secondInstance
 set firstInstance.column_B = 
         (IF(sIFNULL(secondInstance.column_B,0) + 12 >= 0, 
                                        IFNULL(secondInstance.column_B,0) + 12, 0) 
             +firstInstance.column_A)
 where  DATEDIFF(secondInstance.date, firstInstance.date) = 1;
```

SELECT Query:

```
 SELECT firstInstance.DATE, firstInstance.COLUMN_A,
       (IF(IFNULL(secondInstance.column_B,0) + 12 >= 0, 
                                         IFNULL(secondInstance.column_B,0)+ 12, 0) 
             +firstInstance.column_A) AS COLUMN_B
 FROM table1 firstInstance 
 LEFT JOIN tabe1 secondInstance
 ON  DATEDIFF(secondInstance.date, firstInstance.date) = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks! I re-formulated the question. This can't be an update. It has to be a SELECT. I want to have a table with Date, Column_A (both already know) and Column_B populated from formula above

Comment: @user1020283:  Updated the answer for `select` query as well. Please check.

Comment: Thanks! how about without DATEDIFF?

Comment: @user1020283 You may use `INTERVAL 1 DAY` after against `firstInstance.date` before comparing against `secondInstance.date` in the join condition.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add an Identity column to your table as ID?
if yes ... you can use below code:

```
    DECLARE   @count INT;
    DECLARE   @i INT;
    DECLARE  @temp INT;
    SET @count =( select count(*) from myTBL)
    SET @i=2
    WHILE (@i <=@count)
         BEGIN
             SET @temp=(select Column_A from myTBL where ID=@i)+ (select Column_B from myTBL where ID=@i-1);
             IF (@temp>0)      update myTBL set Column_B=@temp where ID=@i
             ELSE update myTBL set Column_B=0  where ID=@i
         SET @i = @i+1
         END
```

Comment: I should add this comment: @i is initialized to 2 ... because we know in advance that first row is not empty!